# How to send a hyperlink to a mobile via SMS or MMS

Tags: hyperlink, sms, mms

I have been looking for a way to send a hyperlink of a URL with a different appearance to a mobile phone via SMS or MMS.

The only example of this that i can think of is the following:

```
[url=http://www.google.co.uk]Click Here[/url]
```

So the above code will show:

> Click Here

when you click the 'Click Here' link it will open up `http://www.google.co.uk`.

Is there anyway that this can be replicated by using SMS or MMS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there is not a generally accepted specification for rendering text messages with modern content. Though certain mobile operating systems (or rather messaging applications to be precise) might support inline links, it is not fail-proof and it won't work on every device.

Also, those smart-ish applications would not rely on a custom syntax but rather search for urls and make those clickable. That means it's not possible to set a custom text for a hyperlink in this context.

Answer (score 0):

You can´t include hiperlinks in text messages, although most mobile browsers allow click in links. Also You could send a wap push (it´s a special binary sms) that it includes one link.