# vb.net send mms text with hyperlink

Tags: vb.net, hyperlink, mms

I am not yet finding my answer anywhere else on the web.

I need to send out an MMS text from my web app (VB.NET) and that text message needs to include a clickable hyperlink.

My current code is:

```
Msg = "Your documents are now ready for pickup. Located" _
          & " in Box 7 " _
          & " Please download the support App. " _
          & "<a href=\"https://linksandroidurlhere.com\">Android</a>" _
          & " or " _
          & "<a href=\"https://linksIOSurlhere.com\">IOS</a>" _
          & " to access your keys."

Dim MsgB64 As String = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Msg))

Dim textURL As String = "http://www.ct.com/PushNotificationsendTextB64.aspx?Phone=" & ownerPhone & "&Content=" & MsgB64
Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
```

This 'sort of' works, but the hyperlinks are not coming through the MMS as links.  Instead, they are coming through as 'as-is" text.

How can I format the hyperlinks within the text such that they will come through the MMS transmission as links?

Comment: You can't. SMS/MMS doesn't support formatting like that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send a hyperlink to a mobile via SMS or MMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496035/how-to-send-a-hyperlink-to-a-mobile-via-sms-or-mms)